# solving a non linear (log-linear) recurrence relation

Tags: difference-equations

I'd like to solve the recurrence relation

$$\begin{align*} f(n+1) &= 2 f(n)^2 h(n) \\ h(n+1) &= h(n) f(n) \\ f(2) & = h(2) = 2 \end{align*}$$ for an explicit solution for $h$ and $f$. So far I found out that I can use `RSolve` and came up with following code:

```
RSolve[ {f[n + 1] == 2 f[n]^2 h[n], h[n + 1] == h[n] f[n], h[2] == 2, f[2] == 2}, {h[n], f[n]}, n ]
```

Whenever I enter this code, I just get the same code back so I must be doing something wrong, but I cannot find out what. Strangely it immediately returns a result if I enter decoupled recurrence relations with the *exact* same syntax.

```
RSolve[ {f[n + 1] == 2 f[n], h[n + 1] == h[n]^2, h[2] == 2, f[2] == 2}, {h[n], f[n]}, n ]
```

Both are basically simple affine recurrence relations if you logarithmise them, which could be solved by linear algebra. Can anyone spot the mistake I'm making?

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in your second `RSolve` expression.

Comment: Sorry, that happened during the copy/pasting, I fixed it now.

Comment: Your second `RSolve` works for me, returning terms like `{f[n] -> 2^(-1 + 2^(-1 + n)), h[n] -> 2}`.  I'm using Mathematica 10.4

Comment: @mikado Yes that is why I included that verison, but the first one does not seem to work, can you confirm that?

Comment: Like you, the first `RSolve` returns unevaluated very rapidly.  I can't see any obvious mistakes in it, so I guess that Mathematica must recognise it as something it can't handle.

Comment: @mikado Thanks, I was just not sure what was happening, as I never reall used Mathematica before. As I said, it would be quite easy if we apply the logarithm on both sides. Is there a *Mathematica*-way of doing this? (Instead of doing it 'by hand' and entering it again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggest, this can be solved quite easily with a `Log` transform.  E.g.

```
eqn = {f[n + 1] == 2 f[n]^2 h[n], h[n + 1] == h[n] f[n], h[2] == 2, f[2] == 2};
leqn = Map[Log, eqn, {2}] // PowerExpand
transform = {Log[f[u_]] -> lf[u], Log[h[u_]] -> lh[u]};
lsoln = RSolve[leqn /. transform, {lf[n], lh[n]}, n]
{f[n] == Exp[lf[n]], h[n] == Exp[lh[n]]} /. lsoln
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much! Could you explain what `/.` is doing / give me a reference? I tried googling it but obviously without success=)

Comment: @flawr, instead of googling it, highlight it in the notebook you have and press F1.

Comment: Oh great, thank you!